# Beamer: Modify section navigation warsaw

Tags: beamer

I'm using `warsaw` theme in LaTeX, and I want to know how to modify `sectionnavigation`, in order to use bold police for current section instead of lightning current section. And I don't want to make other sections in navigation bar looks shaded.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily by putting the following lines in your preamble, after the `\usetheme{Warsaw}`

```
\usesectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill{\bfseries\insertsectionhead}}
  {\hfill\insertsectionhead}
```

**More explanations:**

If you look at the source code of Warsaw, you see that Warsaw is using the outer theme *shadow*, and that shadow relies on *split*. At the beginning of the `beamerouterthemesplit.sty`, you find some color definitions and

```
\usesectionheadtemplate
  {\hfill\insertsectionhead}
  {\hfill\color{fg!50!bg}\insertsectionhead}
```

that defined the way the title of your sections will appear in the headline of your presentation; the first item corresponds to the current section, the second one to the other sections. You see that you will get something shaded for the other sections (`fg!50!bg` meaning 50% of the foreground color and 50% of the background color; if you don't know this way of declaring colors in Beamer keep it in mind, it is very useful (and you can replace `fg` and `bg` by `red`, `blue`, `green` etc.)) so the first things to do is just to remove it. Then, you want the current section to be in bold face, therefore you just have to add the `\bfseries` to get it.

Comment: thank you. That's exactly what I want to do. Sorry I cannot vote yet ! :/